# Where is the space from LVM partitions?

Tags: partition, lvm, disk-usage, disk, partition-table

[image]

Additionally, output from my `df -h` command and `fdisk -l` command.
Where and how could I utilize space from my `/dev/sda4` and `/dev/sda5` partitions? I suspect `/dev/mapper/fedora-root` to be my LVM partition but how come the GNOME disk utility and terminal commands differ in size measurements? How can I add more space to my system, I am at 98% I shrunk the size of my dual booted windows OS and received 18 GB in free space, although I shouldn't even need to use this as I am trying to identify where and how I can utilize space form `/dev/sda4` and `/dev/sda5`

Am I confusing logical and extended partitions from LVM partitions?

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.8G  436K  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    3.8G  1.7M  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                    3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   27G   25G  559M  98% /
tmpfs                    3.8G   76K  3.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda3                477M  163M  285M  37% /boot
tmpfs                    779M  8.0K  779M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                    779M   20K  779M   1% /run/user/1000
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0700565b

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   2459647   2457600  1.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         2459648 152004607 149544960 71.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       186820608 187844607   1024000  500M 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       187844608 250068991  62224384 29.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       187846656 250068991  62222336 29.7G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 26.7 GiB, 28613541888 bytes, 55885824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 3 GiB, 3242196992 bytes, 6332416 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes



lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/fedora/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                fedora
  LV UUID                MvfHav-JZle-0R8m-aH8l-Rf70-n36N-yozEmW
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2015-12-27 19:21:28 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                3.02 GiB
  Current LE             773
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/fedora/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                fedora
  LV UUID                DQ5ikG-0gNP-Mv2m-nthN-LxQr-XrXS-4g54b2
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2015-12-27 19:21:28 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                26.65 GiB
  Current LE             6822
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

[root@localhost ~]# vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               fedora
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               29.67 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              7595
  Alloc PE / Size       7595 / 29.67 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               iXb2mB-6RVd-Cb20-j2Jd-w4Dk-k1WJ-BFTv1t
```

Comment: Where exactly you want to increase your space, show us the output of `lvdisplay` and `vgdisplay`

Comment: @AngRed I want to expand the space on my `/dev/mapper/fedora-root` root parition as I have only 2% disk space left. I updated my question with the output of those commands.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular scenario, you have 3 primary and 1 extended partition. If you look at the output of
`fdisk -l`
and pay attention to /dev/sda2 End and /dev/sda3 Start, you have a bit of space there.

My guess is that your only option is to move data from /dev/sda3 (/boot) partition over network or with some external media (USB etc), unmount /boot, delete /dev/sda3 and create new (or see if you can resize it without deleting) using all space available, run `pvcreate /dev/sda3`, run `vgextend fedora /dev/sda3`, and then use can finally run `lvextend -r -l 100%FREE /dev/mapper/fedora-root`

Finally you can bring files back into /boot directory, only this time it will not have it's separate file system. You can create an lvm and mount it on /boot if you don't use all of the free space extending / file-system.

Any issues, please let me know.

Comment: `/boot` needs to be a separate filesystem, even a primary partition for `grub` and boot to work.